# Type List takes type parameters (Compilation Error in Play )

Tags: scala, playframework

Am currently learning the basics of RESTFUL API, with Play and am getting issues: am following some longtime tutorial and think am failing with right scala syntax! need help, thanks
[here is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j96y.png)

```
 package controllers

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext


class PlacesController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder, ec: ExecutionContext, configuration: Configuration)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {


  case class PlacesController(id: Int, name: String)

  val thePlaces: List = List(
    thePlaces(1, "newyork"),
    thePlaces(2, "chicago"),
    thePlaces(3, "capetown")
  )

  implicit val thePlacesWrites = Json.writes[PlacesController]

  def listPlaces = Action {
    val json = Json.toJson(thePlaces)
    Ok(json)
  }}
```

Comment: `val thePlaces: List` (+ shadowing `thePlaces` name). Highly recommend to read the [doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/overview.html) and some Scala tutorial first

Comment: Also, when you are getting a compilation error, you should include the error in your question.

Comment: have linked the error screenshot

Comment: Paste error, no error screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer, hope this can be of help to some other person in future!!

```
class PlacesController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder, ec: ExecutionContext, configuration: Configuration)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {


  case class PlacesController(id: Int, name: String)

  val thePlaces: List[(Int, String)] = List(
    (1, "newyork"),
    (2, "chicago"),
    (3, "capetown")
  )

  implicit val thePlacesWrites = Json.writes[PlacesController]

  def listPlaces = Action {
    val json = Json.toJson(thePlaces)
    Ok(json)
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with your code. You are defining `thePlaces` while calling `thePlaces` itself on the right-hand-side of the definition.

Also, your naming is confusing.

Try this:

```
final case class Place(id: Int, name: String)

object Place {
  implicit val placeWrites = Json.writes[Place]
}

class PlacesController ... {

  val thePlaces: List[Place] = List(
    Place(1, "newyork"),
    Place(2, "chicago"),
    Place(3, "capetown")
  )

  def listPlaces = Action {
    val json = Json.toJson(thePlaces)
    Ok(json)
  }
}
```